# Is there a way to change the scope of a variable in cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As im creating a dynamic page, I try to access two variables that are modified by a foreach loop. The variable becomes **unassigned** after the loop even if I declared them outside.

I know I should find a way to make an **sql joint**, but this problem keeps occurring whenever I try to access a variable prior to a loop. I searched a way to stop the garbage collector from deleting the variable altogether, but I need a cleaner way to do this.

```cs
@foreach (var item in db.Horraire)
{
    String Employe;
    String color;
        foreach (var search in db.Employé)
        {
            if (search.id == item.EmployeID) { Employe = search.naming; break; }
        }
        foreach (var search in db.Tâche)
        {
            if (search.id == item.EmployeID) { color = search.coloring; break; }
        }
//Turning worked hour into size of occupied red square on a calendar, it's working properly
    TimeSpan substract = item.fin.Subtract(item.début);
    float phours = substract.Hours * 70; phours = phours + substract.Minutes * (60/70);
    String pheight = ""+phours+"px";
    float thours = item.début.Subtract(new DateTime()).Hours + item.début.Subtract(new DateTime()).Minutes/60 - 8; thours = thours * 70 + 110;
    String theight = ""+thours+"px";
    int lday = item.Jour * 200 + 200;
    String ljour = "" + lday + "px";
<div class="redsquare" style="
    position: absolute; width:200px; height:@pheight;
    top:@theight;
    left:@ljour;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
    color: @color;"> //missing local variable
    @Employe //missing local variable
</div>
}
```

Both variables becomes error *"Use of unassigned local variable"* instead of just injecting the variable into the html. How can I fix, either the joint, the **scope of the variable** or the garbage collection?

Comment: If the condition inside the loop is not verified, then the variable is never assigned. So either assign a value in this case or use LINQ instead: `db.Employé.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.EmployeID)`

Comment: You should filter `db.Employé.Where(search => search.id == item.EmployeID)` instead of looping through all your db records!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "the garbage collector from deleting the variable altogether", nor with the scope of the variable.

While you may be certain that the `foreach()` will definitely assign your variables, the C# compiler isn't. And rightfully so.

So you need to definitely assign them with a sensible default value:

```
String Employe = "";
String color = "";
```

But there are many more problems with your code. The fix from your answer:

```
@db.Tache.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.EmployeID).coloring;
@db.Employe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.EmployeID).naming;
```

Will throw a `NullReferenceException` when `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`. So you'll have to add a null check, or simply call `First()` instead. Which, in turn, will throw when there are no matching records in your database.

The solution indeed is to join your tables when querying:

```
@foreach (var item in db.Horraire.Include(h => h.Employé).Include(h => h.Tâche))
{
    // ...

    <div style="color: @item.Tâche.coloring">@item.Employé.naming</div>
}
```

But you really shouldn't run queries in your view, you should do this in your controller and populate a view model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer and the direction to the LINQ language that I simply didn't knew about. Here is the new line that avoid the scope mess

```cs
@db.Tache.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.EmployeID).coloring;
@db.Employe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.EmployeID).naming;
```